# HTML report should contain hyperlink which expands and hides in html report itself

Tags: java, html

I am generating html report in my selenium with java script and I want hyperlink in report for passed results which should expand and hide in report itself. My hyperlink content is jsonstring

I am able to generate link in results now but that link is pointed to files in specific folder on desktop. I need link to expand in report itself without dependency on local files saved on local folder. I need to run this through jenkins on global linux platform later so dont want any dependency on local files and folder

expected explained above

Comment: Hi Rohit, welcome to the Stack Overflow. Could you kindly show what you have tried?  Some code or any preview of what you are trying to achieve? That helps your question to be more answerable :)

Comment: for e.g : I have json string response as , response = {"name": "rohan","age":32} . I want to pass this as hyperlink in html report where in report a link should be displayed with feature to expand the link and view the content . link name for e.g : vTestCase01 ......and this link should contain above data and we should be able to expand the link in report itself . i.e when this report is emailed to my mail id this link should be get expanded with above content . May be use of jsp servelet or soemthing . how to use it ?

Comment: If your response to a comment includes significant information you are encouraged to [edit] the question and add it there as well, or in concert with a reply comment indicating that you have done so. This improved the question and makes it so that other people don't have to dive into the comments in order to get the full picture of what you are asking.

Comment: String linkContents = "<a href = file:\\\\" + refLink +"> " + linkText + "</a>";
  System.out.println("The linkContents::" + linkContents);                                              I am doing it like this and appending it in "td" in html reporting. I need to append link to html report which expands on the report itself . As of now I am saving my result in one folder and passing the path in html report to that file .